# Sourcing an R script whenever a package is loaded

Tags: r, automation, package

I'm creating an R package for the handling of a specific dataset that is regularly updated in our organization, but not on a fixed schedule (making it unsuitable for something such as a cronjob). As a result, users must currently run a set of two scripts for data processing before they begin to analyze the data. In converting this set of functions into a package, I'm hoping to alleviate this by having the scripts be called whenever the package is first loaded to R (with analogous functions if people would like to manually check for an update in the middle of a multi-day session).

I've seen ways to deal with compiling external files upon package installation, but nothing on how to get R to run a script whenever the package is loaded (not just installed). Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions are outlined in the [Writing R Extensions Guide](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html), (which, if you're writing a package, you should be reading carefully) specifically [section 1.5.3 Load Hooks](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Load-hooks)

You can define an `.onLoad` function that will be called when you package loads.